# Can Dijkstra's algorithm be used to find the quickest way to return to the route node?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, graph, dijkstra

I have a directed graph with Nodes ABCDEFGH.

I have Dijkstra working so I can find the quickest route from A-F (for example).

If I wanted to find the quickest path from A-A, would Dijkstra's be the appropriate algorithm to use?

Comment: A-A?  Quickest path is not to do anything.

Comment: Sure, but say I had to find the shortest journey (meaning traversal is required)

Comment: I would just compute Dijkstra's algorithm starting at each neighbour of A, add on the corresponding edge weight, then find the minimum.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I would have it the other way around, since then only one run if Dijkstra's is needed (start from source, and check all candidates which have an outgoing node to the source: `min { d(s,v) + w(v,s) } | for all v such (v,s) is an edge }` ).

Comment: @amit - Yes, you're correct.

Comment: I'm at a complete loss here if I'm honest.

Comment: Would creating an A2, with the same edges as A1 (but disconnected from A1) be a viable solution?

Comment: This is called the traveling salesman problem, and here is the question answered: http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1749/dijsktras-algorithm-applied-to-travelling-salesman-problem

Comment: The traveling salesman wants to visit all the nodes, which doesn't solve the issue

Comment: Sorry, then what do you mean with 'traversal is required'

Comment: So it means I have to find the shortest route to go from A-A. Something like A-B-C-A.

Comment: Then I think your Idea with A1 and A2 is good. Only a loop A-A must be transformed to an edge A1.A2, i think.

Comment: Any chance you could elaborate? Sorry, just I tried it visually (b-b) (http://imgur.com/X8PNeUS), and you just travel back down the path you started with. A visual depiction would be amazing if you happen to have one.

Comment: @spogebob92 In an undirected graph this is the behavior to expect. However, you said you have a directed graph. The behavior is going to be different there.

Comment: @spogebob92: sorry again, i wrote thomething stupid and deleted it.

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you want to get back to the same node from where you have started the concept of TS(travelling salesman) come in play given traversing through all the node(ABCDEFGHA).
you can check TS below

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TravelingSalesmanProblem.html